# Unwanted navigator-like input field at the top of each editor tab in eclipse debugger perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm not sure what I have pressed when debugging, but now all my editor tabs have additional input field at the top which shows something like pkg->class->method. Thankfully, this navigation input is not present in Java perspective. How can I nuke this thingy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A screenshot would be helpful.

If by the "additional input field" you mean the *breadcrumb*, then there's an option to show/hide it on the tool bar:

[image: breadcrumb on toolbar]

Comment: It was "breadcrumb" -- if only I knew the right keyword to goggle! BTW, this is the second time I'm undoing it -- either artifact of my poor memory skills, or testimony of improperly designed feature.

Comment: Could be closable more easily, yes... But why would one want to turn it off, I don't know. I miss it in Eclipse CDT :)